# С чего начать разработку и создание своих собственных тем и стилей для android приложения

Tags: java, android, themes

В приложении всегда используется стандартные темы `Theme.Material.Light, Theme.Holo.Light`. Где можно найти другие темы и стили для своего приложения, или как их создать самостоятельно используя только средства `android studio`?

Comment: Я голосовал за "оставить закрытым" и поскольку [поиск библиотек, программ, плагинов и прочего запрещен](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - нужно оставить вопрос _в данной формулировке_ закрытым. С другой стороны я готов переоткрыть данный вопрос если останется только "как создать тему" без "поиска" в разных сторах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть разные темы для приложений. Их можно найти на превью макета на верхней панели:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь есть темы не только для приложения в целом но и для отдельных его элементов, например AlertDialog. Так же вы можете создавать свои собственные темы и стили в редакторе тем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в этом редакторе вы можете настроить цветовую гамму каждого элемента вручную, выбрав нужный цвет самостоятельно. Так же вы можете создавать собственные стили для своих виджетов. В папке `res->values` есть файл `styles.xml` где можно прописать все стили которые вы хотите видеть примененными на своих виджетах.

Так же одним из способов кастомизации элементов экрана есть создание специальных файлов в папке `drawable`. Например таким образом вы сможете изменить поведение кнопки при изменении ее состояния (в фокусе, нажата, неактивна, недоступна).

Надеюсь я помог в решении вашего вопроса. Если что-то будет непонятно то не стесняйтесь и спрашивайте. Если у кого-то есть еще какие-то пожелания по изменению моего ответа, или дополнения то я с радостью дополню свой ответ.